# How to set style for zoom out rectangle

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I am using LightningChartJs and i'm trying to find a way to style the zoom out rectangle but am unable to locate a method for that.
Please point me towards it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zoom out rectangle is called "fitting rectangle" in the APIs. You can change the fitting rectangle stroke style with [`setFittingRectangleStrokeStyle`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/classes/chartxy.html#setfittingrectanglestrokestyle) and the fill style with [`setFittingRectangleFillStyle`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v1.3.1/classes/chartxy.html#setfittingrectanglefillstyle).

```js
const {
  lightningChart,
  ColorHEX,
  SolidFill
} = lcjs

const {
  createProgressiveRandomGenerator
} = xydata

const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY()

chart.setFittingRectangleStrokeStyle(style => style
    .setFillStyle(fill => fill.setColor(ColorHEX('#f00')))
  )
  .setFittingRectangleFillStyle(new SolidFill({
    color: ColorHEX('#50f0')
  }))

const series = chart.addLineSeries()

createProgressiveRandomGenerator()
  .setNumberOfPoints(100)
  .generate()
  .toPromise()
  .then(data => {
    series.add(data)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/xydata@1.2.1/dist/xydata.iife.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@1.3.1/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```